# How can I install Emscripten with clang 9?

Tags: emscripten

I want to use the latest Asyncify (a.k.a Bysyncify) on Emscripten.

[The blog post](https://kripken.github.io/blog/wasm/2019/07/16/asyncify.html) says that you need the version of Emscripten using clang 9.0.0+.
I installed the latest one (1.38.40) but it uses clang 6.0.1.

How can I install Emscripten with clang 9?

Comment: Don't add "SOLVED" to the title. Instead, *accept* your answer by pressing the green tick to the left of it to mark your question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution right after posting my question.

```
./emsdk install latest-upstream
```